# Regex match used to filter and ArrayList<String> that ignores punctuation within the string

Tags: java, android, regex, arraylist, filter

I have an ArrayList that contain names of various locations that I need to filter as the user types in text.

For example: if the user types **“St Ant”** my filter should include the name **“St. Anthony”**, or if the user types **“Siaes”** my filter should include **“Siae’s Corner”**.

I’m currently using the following if statement as my filter:

`if(placeName().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase()))`

where filter is the user input text.

Thanks in advance for any suggested approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to prepare locations names and filter prior to check

ie

```
if(placeName().Remove(".' ").toLowerCase().contains(filter.Remove(".' ").toLowerCase()))
```